# Legend doesn't appear in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

So I am having trouble getting my legend to appear for my graph. I know I am working with two data sets. And I added the aes() function, but it is still not working.

```
shear_stress <-c(0.637,1.335,2.8,5.874,12.32,25.84,54.19,113.7,238.4,500)
five_glycerol <- data.frame(shear_rate,shear_stress)
five_glycerol

shear_rate2 <-c(6.492,33.67,60.42,102.8,129.4,156.4,182.7,209.8,236.1,263.2)
shear_stress2 <- c(0.637,1.335,2.8,5.874,12.32,25.84,54.19,113.7,238.4,500)
fifteen_glycerol <- data.frame(shear_rate2, shear_stress2)
fifteen_glycerol


p = ggplot() + geom_smooth(data = five_glycerol, aes(x = shear_rate, y = shear_stress), aes(color = "green"))+
  geom_smooth(data = fifteen_glycerol, aes(x = shear_rate2, y = shear_stress2), aes(color = "red"))+ xlab("Shear Rate")+ ylab("Shear Stress")
print(p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You have two `aes()` calls in one `geom_*()` call. Try the following

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = shear_rate, y = shear_stress, color = "Five glycerol"), data = five_glycerol) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = shear_rate2, y = shear_stress2, color = "Fifteen glycerol"), data = fifteen_glycerol) + 
  xlab("Shear Rate") + 
  ylab("Shear Stress")
```

[image]

Next you can change the colour with `scale_colour_discrete(values = c('red', 'green'))` or any other colours.